# SetAttribute refusing to work with TextArea?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

**Hi, new here so I am trying to keep it specific as possible but if it's not, please just tell me nicely and I'll give more info below. :)**

I'm currently making a automated message sender for the game ROBLOX, and I had it working before but they recently changed the interface and basically the entire site design / build so it broke and I'm running into a issue.

So I am familiar with SetAttribute, and that's what it used before the update. But clearly something is not working here

I currently have this:

```
    Private Sub connect_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles connect.DocumentCompleted
        Try
            connect.Document.GetElementById("subject").SetAttribute("value", Form1.subject.Text)
            connect.Document.GetElementById("body").SetAttribute("value", Form1.enter.Text) ' This is the line I'm having issues with
            connect.Document.GetElementById("send-btn").InvokeMember("click")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ErrorToString())
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The subject line and the button are working fine, but it's not filling in the the TextArea for "enter"

This is the code for the textarea on the ROBLOX site, remember I don't work there so I cannot change it to fit my needs.

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="20" id="body" class="messages-reply-box text-box text" style="padding:5px;width:675px;"></textarea>
```

So I'm not quite sure why it's not working, I have the ID right and it works with the other textbox (the subject)

This is Visual Basic, FYI.

Comment: The "value" of a textarea is not an attribute, but the innerText of the textarea-element (value is between the opening and closing tags).

Comment: This should do the trick: `connect.Document.GetElementById("body").InnerText = Form1.enter.Text` ([`HtmlElement.InnerText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext.aspx))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "value" of a textarea is not an attribute, but the InnerText ([`HtmlElement.InnerText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext.aspx)) of the textarea-element (value is between the opening and closing tags).

Change

```
connect.Document.GetElementById("body").SetAttribute("value", Form1.enter.Text)
```

To

```
connect.Document.GetElementById("body").InnerText = Form1.enter.Text
```